# Binding ribbon text box IsEnabled to checkbox IsChecked not working

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

Here is the sample XAML:

```
...
<ribbon:RibbonTab Header="MyTab">
  <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Blah">
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" 
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox}" />
    <ribbon:RibbonCheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" Label="some text" />
  </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
...
```

For some reason, the text box stays disabled regardless of whether or not the check box is checked. Why is the binding not working properly?

You can add the above code minus the elipses at the top and bottom to a boiler plate WPF ribbon project and see if you can figure out what's wrong. I see no binding error diagnostics, for example.

**Update**: If a regular `TextBox` is substituted for the `RibbonTextBox`, the behavior becomes correct. I conclude that there must be some issue with binding the IsEnabled property of a `RibbonTextBox`.

**Freaky update #2**: Creating a basic `RibbonTextBox` and setting its `IsEnabled` property to `True` creates a disabled RibbonTextBox. What gives?

I have submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723134/the-isenabled-property-of-the-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf-ribbontextbox-control-does-not-function-properly#details) on Microsoft Connect to further pursue this issue.

**Final update**: It's [fixed in WPF 4.5](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633097).

Comment: what diagnostics have you done?

Comment: Well I see no binding errors in the WPF diagnostics, if that's what you mean..

Comment: hook onto the RibbonTextBox's IsEnabledChanged and RibbonCheckBox's Checked event and what happens in the callbacks?

Comment: IsEnabledChanged is only called once for the RibbonTextBox (on startup). It does not get called when the check box checked state changes. I am not sure what to do with the Checked event - it does get triggered when the check box is checked/unchecked, but I don't know where to go from there (i.e., how to check why the binding is not working)...

Comment: try specifying ElementName=, then Path= ..

Comment: tried that, no change in behavior

Comment: what happens with a regular TextBox and CheckBox and NOT in a Ribbon?

Comment: As expected, if I change them to a regular TextBox and a regular CheckBox IN the same ribbon group where I tested their ribbon counterparts, everything works perfectly. Of course, the behavior and look and feel differs from the ribbon versions of these controls.

Comment: I tried more permutations of Ribbon vs non-ribbon versions and posted my conclusion in an update to the original question. Also, check out my second update.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, have you tried fully qualifying the property?

```
IsEnabled="{Binding RibbonCheckBox.IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox}"
```

... or maybe even...

```
IsEnabled="{Binding CheckBox.IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox}"
```

Comment: Yep, IsEnabled is just broken due to a bug in RibbonCheckBox. No way around it.

Comment: Are you certain that there is no way around it? You can do wonders with `Attached Properties`. See this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) if you're interested.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633097/ribbontextbox-isenabled-property-is-always-false